# Using unqualified name for static method Equals of class string

Tags: c#, equals

By mistake I wrote

```
Equals( s1, s2 );
```

instead of

```
string.Equals( s1, s2 );
```

and the MS VS compiler compiled the code successfully.

Why did the compiler find static method Equals? Is it a bug of the compiler?

For example you may write

```
Console.WriteLine("compare {0} to {1}: {2}",
    s1, s2, Equals( s1, s2));
```

but you may not write

```
Console.WriteLine("compare {0} to {1}: {2}",
    s1, s2, Compare(s1, s2));
```

EDIT:
It seems that static function Equals calls non-static member function Equals that can be overwritten in each derived class. So the question is where to see the definition of static function Equals of class object?

Comment: [`Object.Equals(obj1, obj2)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I feel it is `object.Equals(object objA, object objB)` which is a `static` method.

Comment: Equals is a method of System.Object and therefore you have it in the function block

Comment: @Tim Schmelter WHere is there written that in this case I may omit the class name in the method call?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: every clas inherits form object, if your class has no `Equals` the compiler will use `object.Equals`(look at intellisense in visual studio). You don't need to mention the class in general if the method is inside the current class (or one of it's parent classes), but it's good practices anyway.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter I am sorry I do not understand what you have written. For example you may not write simply Compare( s1, s2 ).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: there is no `object.Compare` method and if you refer to `string.Compare` you are not allowed because your class does not inherit from `string` (which is impossible anway because it's `sealed`). That's why you need to state the class explicitly even on static methods: `string.Compare("A", "B")`

Comment: @Tim Schmelter Sorry I have again understood nothing. Could you give a reference to the paragraph of for example the ECMA C# Standard where there is written about this?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: i assume that  the real (and more interesting) question is why you can call a static method of a base class without specifying the class, similar to an instance method? I've yet not found the documentation or specification.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter Well is method Compare is the own method of class string or it si defined in some base class?

Answer (score 4):

Because all classes inherits an `Equals` method from Object class. That's the method you are calling in the first example.

You can omit the class name because you are in the context of `object` class. Consider this simple example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static void FooMethod() { }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public Bar()
    {
        FooMethod();
    }
}
```

Here you can call `FooMethod` by omitting the class name because `Bar` inherits from `Foo`.

---

I don't know where is this specified in the specs exactly (omitting the class name when calling a static method in derived class), but you can have a look at [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx).It says:

> When you define a class to derive from another class, the derived class implicitly gains all the members of the base class, except for its constructors and destructors. The derived class can thereby reuse the code in the base class without having to re-implement it.

Also notice the table in there:

[image]

You can see that both classes inherits from object and it's members. Also if you look at the example you can see that they are also omitting the class name when calling the base class method, in the second constructor of `ChangeRequest` class.

```
public ChangeRequest(string title, string desc, TimeSpan jobLen,
                     int originalID)
{
    // The following properties and the GetNexID method are inherited  
    // from WorkItem. 
    this.ID = GetNextID();
    ...
}
```

Comment: And what? Where is there written that in this case I may omit class name in the name of the method call?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: You called Equals in the context of your class, which inherits Object. The same as with any other **member** method.

Comment: @Marcel N. I am sorry I do not understand what this means. Could you give me the reference to the MSDN documentation that says that I may omit class name if a static method of class object is used?

Comment: |@Marcel N By the way I may not write for example Compare( s1, s2 ). So it is totally unclear what is the "context of the class".

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I cannot find the documentation you want, must be in the C# spec (or may not be specified anywhere, as it is common sense). But not sure what the big deal is. You have static method `Equals` in your base class (which is Object) and you can call it in your subclass without prefixing the base class to it. Maybe this can shed some light: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645629(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @Marcel N. Each man his his own "common sense". See my updated post.

Comment: @Marcel N. Moreover in my example there is no any "class context" as in your example.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I don't know how else to put it. Class methods, class scope, etc.

Comment: +1 for the documentation although it does mention `static` explicitly.

Comment: @Marcel N. Method Equals is a static method. Other classes redefine it. So it is not ckear if it is the method of class objuect then how it knows that two strings are compared and not two objects?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow a static method can't redefined or overrided because it doesn't belong to a specific instance it belongs to the calss itself, I think you should understand what _static_ means first.

Comment: @Selman22 Then how does the method know that two strings are compared?

Comment: it doesn't know. it takes objects. not strings, since string also inherits from object, that's why you can call pass strings to the Equals method.

Comment: @Selman22 Do you want to say that it simply compares references? That is behaviours of Equals( s1, s2 ) and s1.Equals( s2 ) are different.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: no, that would be the case if you'd call `ReferenceEquals(str1, str2)`. I suggest to read the [documentation of `object.Equals(str1, str2)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k(v=vs.110).aspx) which explains exactly what it does. Since `string` overrides the instance method `Equals` that is used: `str1.Equals(str2)`. But before the "cheap" `ReferenceEquals` and null-checks are used.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my question myself.

Static method `Equals` within its body calls virtual non-static method `Equals`. As this non-static method `Equals` is overwritten for class `string` then the static method makes correct comparison.
The static method is called without class name because all claeses are derived from class object.